# How to send request scope bean as response in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, requestscope

I would need to send the response which also consists of request information as well. Tried with the following code but getting below exception:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class OrderResponse {
     private String discountDetails;
     private boolean confirmedStatus;
     private OrderDto orderDetails;
     private String shortMsg;
     private int status;
     //Getter & Setters
}

public class OrderDto {
     private int quantity;
     private String product;
     //Getters & Setters
}
```

Controller & Advice classes:

```
@RestController
    @RequestMapping(value = "/orders")
    public class OrderController {
         @Autowired
         private OrderResponse orderResponse;
         ....
         @PostMapping(value = "/order/placeOrder")
         public ResponseEntity<OrderResponse> placeOrder(@RequestBody OrderDto orderDto){
           ....
           orderResponse.setOrderDetails(orderDto);//Adding request details to the response
           ....
           return new ResponseEntity<>(orderResponse, HttpStatus.OK); 
         }
    }

@RestControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = OrderController.class)
public class OrderExceptionHandler {
     @Autowired
     private OrderResponse orderResponse;

     @ExceptionHandler(value = DataAccessException.class)
     protected ResponseEntity<OrderResponse> constraintHandling(DataAccessException ex) {
        ....
        orderResponse.setShortMsg(shortMsg);
        orderResponse.setStatus(200);
        ....
        return new ResponseEntity<>(orderResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
     }
}
```

**Getting below error:**

```
2020-05-10 18:39:34.362 ERROR 12620 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.aop.ClassFilter]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: spring.test.jpa.controllers.OrderResponse$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5deecefd["advisors"]->org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultIntroductionAdvisor[0]->org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultIntroductionAdvisor["classFilter"])] with root cause

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: spring.test.jpa.controllers.OrderResponse$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5deecefd["advisors"]->org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultIntroductionAdvisor[0]->org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultIntroductionAdvisor["classFilter"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1191) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter._handleSelfReference(BeanPropertyWriter.java:944) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
.....
.....
```

Please help on this, Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because both `OrderDTO` and `OrderResponse` are serialized objects. This triggers the self reference error from `Jackson`.

You can configure your `ObjectMapper` bean to disable this.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_SELF_REFERENCES, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time @Tan. It's working fine but getting few additional properties in part of the response (frozen, preFiltered, targetClass, exposeProxy, advisors, targetSource, proxiedInterfaces, proxyTargetClass, targetObject). I restricted those properties from response using @@JsonIgnoreProperties. Please let me know, what would be the reason for getting those properties?. Is there any other way to ignore them?

Comment: Now that I have a better look, why is your `OrderResponse` class autowired? It then becomes a Singleton, which kinda defeats the purpose. Why not just create a new `OrderResponse` everytime you need one? You seem to be working against the convention here

Comment: OrderResponse will be created every request as created with 'request' scope though OrderController is singleton controller class(i checked by placing some dummy msg in @PostConstruct) I think, if its 'prototype' scope, it does create only one in singleton classes. my ultimate goal is to get appropriate request-info and send the client back with some valid msg in advice class (OrderExceptionHandler). So, if i do create new OrderResponse, then i wouldn't able to get request-info in advice classes. Please suggest!!

Comment: If you need request info, you can add `HttpServletRequest` parameter to `constrantHandling` method. Spring will take care of the injection and you'll be able to get your request info. That, or you can autowire `HttpServletRequest` directly in `OrderExceptionhandler` advice. The request is already spring-managed throughout this HTTP call's lifecycle. You don't have to make `OrderResponse` a spring managed bean. Also, what do you need in your response when there's an error? It might make more sense to create another class with only `shortMessage`, `status` and `request` (if needed)